# Show Adaptive card on click of button in modal popup in teams chat

Tags: microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service, imessage-extension

I'm working on a azure bot which is invoked in MS Teams as a custom app. I'm a having a button on Adaptive card on click of which i need to show a modal popup for FAQ's.

I'm trying to achieve this using task module of bot framework and i'm completely new to bot framework. so what could be best possible way to achieve this. i'm using Bot framework v3.

```
var button = new CardAction()
    {
        Title = "Option 1",
        Type = "Submit",
        Value = "{\"option\": \"opt1\"}"
    };
```

Comment: Which SDK are you working in? And, is that the extent of your code or is there more you can share?

Comment: @Mayuresh Jaiswal Please go through the [samples for Task Module](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-task-module-csharp) and try it. Please let us know if you face any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Like Gousia said, if you are using Task Module, you can go through [official sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-task-module-csharp).

Or

a [complete demo code](https://github.com/Office365DevOps/msteams-samples-task-module-csharp), it's from official sample. And including task module triggered in javascript and in adaptive card.

hope helped.